# Windows 8 phone save state

Tags: windows-phone-8

I am quite new to windows 8 phone and I don't know all the life cycle methods and when what is called.

My problem is the following: I have a page that loads some data from the disk and when the user exits the program ( or suspends ) the data should be saved. As far as I can tell Page doesn't have an OnSuspending method only someOnNavigatingFrom, but those are not called when you just exit the program. So I read that I should use the OnSuspending in my App.xaml.cs, but this class doesn't have this data and also shouldn't have it, maybe only for OnSuspending. But I don't know how to get the data from my page in the OnSuspending method.

Answer (score 2):

The OnSuspending event is quite fragile and you cannot expect it to run and save the state for a long time. But it depends on how long it would take for you to save.  It doesn't even get triggered when you hit the home key while closing the app. If you really want an easy way. Just register a background task. While your app is in the background, the state can be saved and when you open the app again things are in place.

There are certain constraints With Background task as well, you cant do heavy lifting etc...here's a link you could use.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh977056.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Implement an observer pattern (i.e. pub/sub) for your view-models to subscribe to in the event that your app is being suspended.

Your app handles the suspended event. As a result, publish a message for your view-models to respond to within your app's method handler for the suspended event.

You can use an [EventAggregator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921122.aspx) or [MessageBus](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Bizmonger.Patterns) (that I wrote).

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer. This seems unnecessary complicated tho. I can't believe that I am the first to have such kind of problem and there not being an elegant way to save data.

Comment: That is an elegant way. It's an engineering approach to support loose coupling. Your app is sending a notification to observers that it is being suspended. Thus, your observers (i.e. view-models) can react to that event in a way that makes sense to to them. Why not take pride in implementing loose coupling and the Single Respnsibility Principle? The approach I listed supports good design. It's not complicated. It's clean.